# Accessing IntelliJ Database from Python

Tags: python, intellij-idea, jdbc

I am using IntelliJ for my Python project.  I have created a database connection under Database where I can run queries with no problem.  So I have a list of .sql files that I would like to run from within python using the existing connection.  How do I go about it?

I can import various packages to pass the queries across to the external database, but since I already have this connection, I was wondering if it was possible to use it to pull data by simply just referring to the connection.

Thanks,

Comment: IntelliJ is not a database system itself, it only provides access to database systems using their JDBC drivers. The answer to your question depends on what database system you are using from IntelliJ. Without more specific information, we can't really help you.

Comment: Agreed. I have made a JDBC connection to Teradata. It is working with out a hitch. I just want to utilize this existing connection in my python. I can do it by using the teradata package but I am thinking if I already established a connection. Why can’t I use it to get data.

Comment: JDBC is Java based, so you can't just use it from Python (without libraries to call Java from within Python). And, you can't use a connection from a different process. Even if you were using Java, you wouldn't be able to use the JDBC connection from IntelliJ in a different Java application. You will need to create a connection from you Python program (preferably using a Python library).

Comment: Mark, thank for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Rightclick on needed database in InteliJ Database tab and click on "Open Console".
There you can paste your sql and run it.

Comment: I would like to run the .sql from within python though, so that I can get the data to a dataframe.